# Intuition of the relationship between laplacian matrix, adjacency matrix and degree matrix

Tags: graph-theory, laplacian, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I was studying graph theory and came across [this](https://csustan.csustan.edu/~tom/Clustering/GraphLaplacian-tutorial.pdf) tutorial. In page 13 it said

The Laplacian matrix $L$ is equal to $D-A$, where $D$ is the degree matrix and $A$ is the adjacency matrix. I am having a hard time to understand the intuition of how people arrive with $L = D-A$ at the first place. Can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 3):

Below is a link that answer about intuition of Laplacian matrix.

https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-intuition-behind-a-Laplacian-matrix-Im-not-so-much-interested-in-mathematical-details-or-technical-applications-Im-trying-to-grasp-what-a-laplacian-matrix-actually-represents-and-what-aspects-of-a-graph-it-makes-accessible

Comment: This explains the discretization of the laplacian operator but it didn't explain why the laplacian matrix is degree matrix minus the adjacency matrix. Can you give me some insights?

Comment: Have you seen the part "Oh! Oh! More comments." of Alex Kritchevsky's answer in the link. I believe it answers your question.